# DataTextField wont work when binding to List

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

```
Public Class Item

    Public Text As String
    Public Value As Integer

End Class

Me.uxDropDown.DataSource = itms
Me.uxDropDown.DataTextField = "Text"
Me.uxDropDown.DataValueField = "Value"
Me.uxDropDown.DataBind()
```

Why does this not work, where itms is a List(Of Item)?

Error event triggered on the line: Me.uxDropDown.DataBind()

DataBinding: 'Project.Item' does not contain a property with the name 'Text'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error would clearly be "DataBinding: 'Item' does not contain a property with the name 'Text'." Change those public variables as public properties instead and your error would go away.

```
Public Class Item
    Private _Text As String
    Private _Value As Integer

    Public Property Text() As String
        Get
            Return _Text
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Text = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Value() As Integer
        Get
            Return _Value
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _Value = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```